# firebase functions:shell does not emulate state of memory between invocations

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I am testing my Cloud Functions with `firebase functions:shell` and realized that it does not seem to emulate the state of memory between invocations.

```
let flag = false;
exports.test = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  console.log(flag); // this is still false on second call :-(
  flag = true;
  return true;
});
```

I know that functions should be stateless but as the doc says “Cloud Functions often recycles the execution environment of a previous invocation.” and this works in production.
Anyone know if there is a way to test this locally ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no way to do this.  The issue is being discussed on GitHub.  [You can follow the issue here.](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/1353)